# How to stop marching ants in Gimp after selection has been made?

Tags: gimp, selections

In the image below, I traced around an object (the yellow-colored candy) using the Paths tool, then clicked on `Selection from Path` in the tool's dialog panel.  However, the marching ants effect around the selection is still active, even after I have filled the selection with color.  How can I stop the marching ants? (And also, why is it still displayed *after* I have made a selection from the path?)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the shortcut for "Select" > "None". I wouldn't be "permanently" toggling edge display if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

The marching formation is for you to remember, what selection still is active. You can still use  the same selection. Press Ctrl + Shift + A to deactivate that selection. It's a good idea at first to save the selection - especially the one that needed some work and isn't easily redoable. You can save it to a path or to a channel or simply fill some area with that selection in an empty layer which is made invisible.

Comment: How can I save a single layer as you have suggested?

Comment: @Sabuncu I suggested "save the selection" -  just in case you want to use it later without a complex reselection for example with the lasso. Create a new empty transparent layer in the layers panel+paint the selection full of some color. Then click that layer invisible. The selection is easily recalled by the magic wand. Saving to path is more advanced way. The active selection can be saved to a path at the bottom of the Select menu. In the Paths panel you can right click a path icon and select Path to selection. All talked stuff will be saved when you save the work as XCF file.