# Marching ants not visible in GIMP -- Setting?

Tags: gimp, selections

My GIMP application is in an odd state, possibly due to a setting that got messed up/corrupted? When I make a selection with any of the selection tools, there is no visual indication of where the selection is, i.e. no marching ants. I didn't find this problem in my searches, but I did find a reference to permanently toggling marching ant visibility -- not how to do it, just "I wouldn't be "permanently" toggling edge display if I were you." in mayersdesign's comment on this thread: [How to stop marching ants in Gimp after selection has been made?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97649/how-to-stop-marching-ants-in-gimp-after-selection-has-been-made)

I tried restarting GIMP, restarting the computer, etc. I am on MacOS 11.5 and GIMP v 2.10.14.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug with Big Sur](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/5952), still awaiting a fix.

A workaround is to use the ["quick mask"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-window-qmask-button.html) or the [selection editor](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-dialog.html) to check you selection.

Btw, 2.10.14 is not the latest (2.10.28 currently).